# i can't create a activity and link button to this activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

i can't create a activity and link button to this activity !!
you can make a project for example and send download link for me ??
this is esay but I am a novice
( android , eclips )

Comment: Post what you have done

Answer (score 1):

in Manifest file create the entry:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="NextActivity"/>
```

on you Activity (FirstActivity - where you have the button):

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first_button_id_here);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution to your *question* is quite simple:

0 Suppose you created both of the Activities: YourActivity is the first One and you want to go to YourSecondActivity

1 Open the XML file of your first activity (your_activity.xml)

2 Add the Button where you want declaring it in this way:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:onClick="goToAnotherActivity" />
```

3 Open your activity's Java file (Something like YourActivity.java)

4 Declare the function:

```
public void goToAnotherActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

5 Try it.

However the solution to your *problem* is another one I think: read some beginner's guide. I learned with Android's ufficial guide here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html